# ORA-12505 for Oracle XE 11g on Windows

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-xe

I'm not able to connect to my locat DB (Oracle XE 11g) using oracle SQL Developer since morning.

I tried shutdown and startup services.

Error message

> **Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
>   ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
>    **

However I'm able to connect as sysdba.

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sat Nov 16 11:54:54 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter password: 
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
SQL>
```

Listener file:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-T9TNRHD)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

TNS file:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-T9TNRHD)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

lsnrctl status: result

```
C:\Users\Leo>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 03-MAY-2018 12:46:53

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-T9TNRHD)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12546: TNS:permission denied
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00516: Permission denied
   64-bit Windows Error: 13: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

what does "lsnrctl status" and "lsnrctl services" show?

Comment: SQL> lsnrctl status
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "lsnrctl st..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: this is not a sql command. this is the tool to manage the listener. run it from your command line like sqlplus.

Comment: looks like your listener is not running or something is missing. try to start with "lsnrctl start"

Comment: did that.. TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Comment: as which user you did that?

Comment: you mean which "windows user" ? 
this is command I executed : C:\Users\Leo>lsnrctl start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170292/discussion-between-marcels-and-leo).